# How can PayPal merchants accept bitcoin?

Tags: merchants, paypal, merchant-services

I've heard [PayPal allows merchants to accept bitcoin](https://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/breaking-paypal-merchants-can-now-accept-bitcoin/); however, I can't find any documentation showing how PayPal merchants can do this. How can a PayPal merchant accept bitcoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Braintree is owned by PayPal so I believe you would have to integrate with them:
https://www.braintreepayments.com/

Comment: I wonder why PayPal doesn't just have an option to turn bitcoin on in their business account settings.

Comment: How exactly do I integrate BrainTree with PayPal? Is there a guide on how to do this somewhere?